# spring boot ResourceBundle not working. What's the trick

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

Can someone explain what I am missing?

The examples are dead simple. In the most basic of applications loads fine and I can get my property:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleAmqpSimpleApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SampleAmqpSimpleApplication.class, args);
        String foo = context.getMessage("foo.name", null, Locale.US);
        System.out.println("*********** " +foo);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return resourceBundleMessageSource;
    }

}
```

output:

> *********** baz

But in my actual app:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableReactor
public class TheOracle {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ac = SpringApplication.run(TheOracle.class, args);
    InputStream friendly = TheOracle.class.getResourceAsStream("/friendly_en_US.properties");
    if(friendly == null)
        throw new RuntimeException();

    String message = null;
    try {
        message = ac.getMessage("foo.name", null, Locale.US);
    } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
        System.out.println("No message");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(friendly);
        message = props.getProperty("foo.name");
    }
    System.out.println(message);
}

@Bean
public MessageSource friendlyNames() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource bundle = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    bundle.setBasename("friendly");
    return bundle;
}
}
```

produces:

> 16:49:22.555 [main] INFO  com.mz.matrix.TheOracle - Started TheOracle
>   in 10.552 seconds (JVM running for 12.993) 
>   No message 
>   baz

original exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found
>   under code 'foo.name' for locale 'en_US'.     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource.getMessage(DelegatingMessageSource.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1232)
>     at com.mz.matrix.TheOracle.main(TheOracle.java:58)

Comment: `getResourceAsStream("/friendly_en_US.properties");` try removing the forward slash.  If the file is in your classpath it should be loaded

Comment: I know that won't work -- I had loaded a file as a resource 1000x times. That's just to demonstrate to the reader that the file I seek is at the root of the classpath

Comment: Your example worked for me.

Comment: The second example worked???

Give me some pointers. What could go wrong in such an easy setup. The files are definitely in the classpath at the root

Comment: Your bean has the wrong name. A `MessageSource` must have the name `messageSource` it is a magic name that is detected by the `ApplicationContext` yours is named `friendlyNames` and not `messageSource`. Hence for the `ApplicationContext` it doesn't exists. ]